# Generating HTML reports in java

Tags: java, html, report

I would like to know the best way to generate reports in java. I have written a small code in java which reads data from my csv file and printing in console. how can i pass this data to my HTML reports.

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for informing me, so can i delete this question?

Answer (score 3):

The two options I would consider for creating an HTML representation of your data are [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) & [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/). Both of these are easy to use template engines that separate the generation & formatting of the output from the Java code which I find improves maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. i will try